# Why do the radio buttons show the value of the previous page and not render unselected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, react-forms

If I select a radio button on the first page and click on "Next", the "same" radio button on the second page is also selected. Why?

I tried to narrow down the example below to the very essential.

I want to keep the pages separated. Furthermore, I also tried to use useForm, but the core problem remains the same.

```
const Example = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  if (page === 1) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>page1</div>
        <input type="radio" name="options1" id="option1_1" value="1" />
        <input type="radio" name="options1" id="option1_2" value="2" />
        <input type="radio" name="options1" id="option1_3" value="3" />
        <button onClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}>back</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>next</button>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div>page2</div>
        <input type="radio" name="options2" id="option2_1" value="1" />
        <input type="radio" name="options2" id="option2_2" value="2" />
        <input type="radio" name="options2" id="option2_3" value="3" />
        <input type="radio" name="options2" id="option2_4" value="4" />
        <button onClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}>back</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>next</button>
      </>
    );
  }
};
```

[Code Sandbox of the example above](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-waterfall-6qxe6n?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you can use `checked` attribute to render the current selected item.

your sandbox link is not proper.

Comment: This is the result of React optimization. It doesn't remove all radio buttons, only add and remove the forth one. If you select it on Page2 and then click Back and Next it becomes unselected. Interesting example by the way.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I fixed the sandbox link in the post above.
@Abhishek Kumar Pandey:
 How can I use the checked attribute if I want to uncheck all radio buttons?

Comment: if you are using radio button, you can not select multiple value at same time, you can only select one at a time. so i am not able to understand your question this question "if I want to uncheck all radio buttons"

Comment: if you click on the link above
1) select any radio button on the page
2) click on the next button
3) see a selected radio button on the second page (but this is an unwanted behavior. On the second page there should not be any button selected as long as the user does not choose any radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this solution. But it is at least a feasible solution.
I wrap the form in an additional `<div>` on every even page so that React recognizes that there is a change on the page.

This is the new code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const { register } = useForm();

  if (page === 1) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>page1</div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options1"
          id="option1_1"
          {...register("q1")}
          value="1"
        />
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options1"
          id="option1_2"
          {...register("q1")}
          value="2"
        />
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="options1"
          id="option1_3"
          {...register("q1")}
          value="3"
        />

        <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>next</button>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div>page2</div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="options2"
            id="option2_1"
            {...register("q2")}
            value="1"
          />
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="options2"
            id="option2_2"
            {...register("q2")}
            value="2"
          />
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="options2"
            id="option2_3"
            {...register("q2")}
            value="3"
          />
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="options2"
            id="option2_4"
            {...register("q2")}
            value="4"
          />

          <button onClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}>back</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the new [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-jepsen-7kj7vj?file=/src/App.js:0-1620).